# How can I get an equals method with many constrants

Tags: java

I'm working on an equals method that will check to see if two points are equal. A single point consists of quantity and price where quantity is an `integer` and price is a `double`. I want the price to stop at the second decimal place which is why I have the TOLERANCE (it is set as 0.01). I am not sure how to get these constraints in the equals(). This is what I have right now:

```
public boolean equals (Point Other)
{
    if((this.quantity == Other.quantity) && (Math.abs(this.price - Other.price)<TOLERANCE)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Say you have (q1,p1) and (q2,p2). I want to be able to use the equals() to see if:

If q1=q2 while p1=p2 or

If q1!=q2 while p1=p2 or

If q1=q2 while p1!=p2 or

If q1!=q2 while p1!=p2

Also in my TestPoint class when in test to see if the points are equal I want it to print out if:

The points are equal

The quantities are not equal, prices are equal

The quantities are equal, the prices are not equal

The points are not equal

Here is what I have now in my tester:

```
   if (p1.equals(p2)) {
          System.out.println("Points are equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Points are not equal");
    }
```

Comment: If you want an "equal within a certain tolerance" method, that shouldn't be `equals`. `equals` must be an equivalence relation, and "equal within a certain tolerance" is not.

Comment: then you need your hashcode has such tolerance too...

Comment: Can you just provides another method, not 'equals', to compare them?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr that is not possible.  (Unless your hashcode function returns the same value for every object.)

Comment: Note that if you are thinking of "stopping at the second decimal place", __you should not be using `double`__.  A `double` cannot store the value 0.01; the value will be an approximation.  See [my site](http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/showfloat.php?floatvalue=.01&floattype=double) for an explanation.  If you want values that are accurate to two decimal places, either use `BigDecimal`, or just store all your price values as integers and make sure you treat them as cents values instead of dollar values.

Comment: @user2357112 Absolutely correct.  But note that if you round values to the nearest 0.01 (assuming you're using `BigDecimal`) and compare the results for equality, it *is* an equivalence relation.  Of course, it also means that 2.138 != 2.146.

Comment: You are overriding the `equals()` method from class `Object`.  This method has a very explicit contract (which you are free to refine but which, for your purpose, I don't think you should).  The `equals()` method will be invoked by collections classes and must be written in tandem with `hashCode()`.  I agree that for your purpose, you should use a custom method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean quantityEqualWith (Point other)    {
    if(this.quantity == other.quantity) return true;
    return false;
}
public boolean priceEqualWith (Point other)    {
    if (Math.abs(this.price - other.price)<TOLERANCE) return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean isEqual(Point other)    {
    if(this.priceEqualWith(other)&&this.quantityEqualWith(other)) return true;
    return false;
}
public boolean isQuantityEqual (Point other)    {
    if((!this.priceEqualWith(other))&&(this.quantityEqualWith(other))) return true;
    return false;
}
public boolean isPriceEqual (Point other)    {
    if((this.priceEqualWith(other))&&(!this.quantityEqualWith(other))) return true;
    return false;
}
public boolean isNotEqual(Point other)    {
    if((!this.priceEqualWith(other))&&(!this.quantityEqualWith(other))) return true;
    return false;
}
```

I don't recommend overriding `equals()`. However, if you insist, you should override `hashcode()` as well.

Comment: *"Not recommend to override method equals()"* ... this is incorrect.  Any class that has a sense of *logical equality* that differs from *identity* MUST override both the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods if instances of the class will be used in ways that depend on equality tests (eg. with the Collections Framework classes).

Comment: Yes, I agree. _"Not recommend to override method equals()"..._ this just aims at the condition in this question.

Answer (score 3):

One of the maxims that Joshua Bloch (Effective Java, 2nd Ed.) offers for overriding `equals()` in Java is the following (paraphrasing):

> You shouldn't try to hard to demonstrate equivalence.  For example,
>   for the `File` class, `equals()` should not take symbolic links into
>   account for demonstrating equivalence.  Thankfully, it doesn't.

As was pointed out in the comments, your purpose is not to look for equality (rather, to look for nearness).  You should not override the `equals()` method for this purpose and I just wanted to take a moment to point out the hazard of doing so in this case (because the signature of your method differs, I note that you aren't overriding equals, you're overloading it ... but still).

The contract for `equals()` from the `Object` class (the parent class for all objects in Java):

- It is **reflexive**: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
- It is **symmetric**: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
- It is **transitive**: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
- It is **consistent**: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
- For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

While the developer is free to *refine* this contract, he may not change it.  The Collections framework, in particular, relies on this contract for correctness.  If you define an `equals()` method that violates this contract, the Collections classes may fail in ways that can be difficult to debug.

Creating an equivalence test based on tolerances can violate the `equals()` contract because of loss of transitivity (the 3rd point in the contract).

To illustrate:

Say you wish to say that objects are equal if an integer field is within +/- 10 of another object's same field

```
myObject a = new myObject(1);
myObject b = new myObject(6);
myObject c = new myObject(11);
```

For these objects:

```
a.equals(b)    evaluates to true
b.equals(c)    evaluates to true
a.equals(c)    evaluates to false
```

Transitivity is violated and thus the equals contract is broken.  Defining an `equals()` method in this way will cause unpredictable behavior for any class that depends on the equals contract for its correctness.  The Collections classes, in particular, will not function properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int comparePriceQuantity(Point Other)
{
    if((this.quantity == Other.quantity)){
         if(Math.abs(this.price - Other.price)<TOLERANCE){
            return 0; // return PQ_EQUAL;
         else
            return 2; // return Q_EQUAL_P_NOT_EQUAL
         }
     }
     else{
        if(Math.abs(this.price - Other.price)<TOLERANCE)
          return 1; // return Q_NOT_EQUAL_P_EQUAL
        else
          return 3; //PQ_NOT_EQUAL

     }

}
```

If q1=q2 while p1=p2 => 0

If q1!=q2 while p1=p2  =>1

If q1=q2 while p1!=p2 =>2

If q1!=q2 while p1!=p2 =>3

Note: Instead of using int, enum should be used for better readability and manageability of code.

enum declaration:

```
public enum PointTestValues{
    QP_EQUAL,
    Q_NOT_EQUAL_P_EQUAL,
    Q_EQUAL_P_NOT_EQUAL,
    PQ_NOT_EQUAL 
}
```

Message Print:

```
public void messagePrint(PointTestValues testResult){
    switch(testResult){
       case QP_EQUAL:
           // print message
           break;
       case Q_NOT_EQUAL_P_EQUAL:
           // print message
           break;
       case Q_EQUAL_P_NOT_EQUAL:
           // print message
           break;
       case PQ_NOT_EQUAL:
           // print message
           break;


    }
}
```

Note: return corresponding enum value instead of int in the method "comparePriceQuantity". I have provided it in comment

Main function:

```
messagePrint(point1.comparePriceQuantity(point2))
```

Comment: Please don't call this `compareTo`.  That is a method defined by classes that implement `Comparable`, and it has very different semantics from what your method does.  Even if your class doesn't implement `Comparable`, it will be very confusing to readers.  Also, I'd consider making the result an `enum` instead of a "0, 1, 2, or 3" value.

Comment: you are right. I over-write the normal property of compareTo method of Comparable that return -1 or 0 or 1. Enum will make the code more readable and manageable. I appreciate your inputs and update it. :)

Comment: When I did this and changed it to enum I got a lot of errors

Comment: @retrogirl19: int version will work fine. I will update the code with enum as well.

Comment: @retrogirl19 : if your query is resolved then please accept the answer. It will help others in finding better answer quickly.